# Merge the value of same key names in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to merge the ids of same name values

```
hashes = [{
    id: 3456824,
    name: 'John'
},{
    id: 6578954,
    name: 'Vicky'
},{
    id: 987456,
    name: 'John'
}]
```

Expected:

```
[{
    id: [3456824,987456],
    name: 'John'
},{
    id: 6578954,
    name: 'Vicky'
}]
```

how I can achieve this in ruby on rails?

Comment: I think the expected result is not a valid hash, You may need the below format `id: [3456824,987456]`?

Comment: @user11350468 year this can also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```rb
hashes = [{
    id: 3456824,
    name: 'John'
},{
    id: 6578954,
    name: 'Vicky'
},{
    id: 987456,
    name: 'John'
}]

result = hashes.group_by{|h| h[:name] }.map{|k, v| {id: v.map{|x| x[:id]}, name: k}}

puts result
```

Check this repl: https://repl.it/repls/ShadowyCornyVideogames

Comment: This returns `[{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"}, {:id=>[6578954], :name=>"Vicky"}]`, whereas `:id=>6578954` was wanted but `[6578954]` is a better choice as it will save time down the road by avoiding the need to check if the value of `:id` is an array. Note that I corrected the array in the question and assigned it to the variable `hashes`. You therefore can remove your definition of that array if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to compute the desired result.

**Use the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block**

```
hashes.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] << g[:id]
end.map { |name,id| { id: id, name: name } }
  #=> [{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"},
  #    {:id=>[6578954], :name=>"Vicky"}]
```

The first step of this calculation<sup>1</sup> is

```
hashes.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] << g[:id]
end
  #=> {"John"=>[3456824, 987456], "Vicky"=>[6578954]}
```

If a hash is defined

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

and (possibly after having added key-value pairs) `h` has no key `k`, `h[k]` in

```
h[k] << v
```

causes the block `{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }` to be executed, resulting in the key value pair `k=>[]` being added to `h`, then `<< v` is executed, changing `h[k]` from `[]` to `[k]`.

---

Notice that this returns `:id=>[6578954]`, rather than `:id=>6578954`, which was asked for by the question. Having all values of `:id` return an array avoids the need to check if `:id` returns an array or integer in subsequent code that processes the return value of this operation.

If `:id=>6578954`, were desired, one could write

```
hashes.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] << g[:id]
end.transform_values { |v| v.size==1 ? v.first : v }.
    map { |name,id| { id: id, name: name } }
  #=> [{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"},
  #    {:id=>6578954, :name=>"Vicky"}]
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

**Use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:name]=>[g[:id]]) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end.map { |name,id| { id: id, name: name } }
  #=> [{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"},
  #    {:id=>[6578954], :name=>"Vicky"}]
```

If `:id=>6578954`, rather than `:id=>[6578954]`, were desired:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:name]=>g[:id]) { |_,o,n| [*o,n] }
end.map { |name,id| { id: id, name: name } }
  #=> [{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"},
  #    {:id=>6578954, :name=>"Vicky"}]
```

Notice that here `update`'s argument is `g[:name]=>g[:id]` whereas it was previously `g[:name]=>[g[:id]]`.

The first step is as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:name]=>g[:id]) { |_,o,n| [*o,n] }
end
  #=> {"John"=>[3456824, 987456], "Vicky"=>6578954}
```

---

In general, one or both of these approaches can be taken when [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) can be used. The reverse if often true also. The choice among these methods is a matter of personal taste.

<sup>1. A variant of the first part of this calculation is `hashes.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| (h[g[:name]] ||= []) << g[:id] } #=> {"John"=>[3456824, 987456], "Vicky"=>[6578954]}`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```rb
args = [{
    id: 3456824,
    name: 'John'
},{
    id: 6578954,
    name: 'Vicky'
},{
    id: 987456,
    name: 'John'
}]

value_pairs = args.map { |h| h.values_at(:name, :id) }
grouped_by_name = value_pairs.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |arr| arr.map(&:last) }
as_hashes = grouped_by_name.map { |name, ids| { id: ids, name: name } }
```

Comment: I want to execute this functionality in the controller and now its showing error `undefined method `values_at'`

Comment: Varinde, by replacing `args` with `hashes`, where the latter is (now) defined in the question, `hashes.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| (h[g[:name]] ||= []) << g[:id] } #=> {"John"=>[3456824, 987456], "Vicky"=>[6578954]}`.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible solution is:

```rb
array = [
  {
    id: 3456824,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 6578954,
    name: "Vicky"
  },
  {
    id: 987456,
    name: "John"
  }
]

grouped_by_name = array.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |hash, result|
  result[hash[:name]] << hash[:id]
end
=> {"John"=>[3456824, 987456], "Vicky"=>[6578954]}

grouped_by_name.map do |grouped_hash|
  {
    id: grouped_hash.last,
    name: grouped_hash.first
  }
end
=> [{:id=>[3456824, 987456], :name=>"John"}, {:id=>[6578954], :name=>"Vicky"}]
```